# In Azure CosmosDB - disable the Data Explorer to user

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

In Azure Portal to user - how to disable the Data Explorer in Azure Cosmos DB service.

Comment: Why do you want to disable the data explorer?(Because this seems like an "X Y question" which means there is a requirement for which disabling data explorer is seen as the solution, but likely there is a different approach to that underlying requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is to restrict users from executing query on Azure portal. You can have a look at [different roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/role-based-access-control) available and control the access level accordingly. In this case what you need is **Cosmos DB Operator**

> Can provision Azure Cosmos accounts, databases, and containers. Cannot
> access any data or use Data Explorer.